# Attribute based custom serialization / deserialization of DateTimeOffset

Tags: json.net

Is it possible to configure JSON.NET to serialize / deserialize a property differently if it's marked with an attribute?

```
public class Person {
    [DateOnly]
    public DateTimeOffset Birthday {get;set;}
}

public class Meeting {
    public DateTimeOffset Date {get;set;}
}
```

Person should serialize to

```
{"Birthday": {"year": 1980, "month": 2, "day": 1}}
```

Meeting should serialize to

```
{"Date": "2012-12-31T21:03:54.735168+00:00"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing custom `JsonConverter` and decorating the `Birthday` property of `Person` class with it. Something like this:

```
public class DateTimeOffsetConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var val = (DateTimeOffset)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("year");
        writer.WriteValue(val.Year);
        writer.WritePropertyName("month");
        writer.WriteValue(val.Month);
        writer.WritePropertyName("day");
        writer.WriteValue(val.Day);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var year = int.Parse(jObject["year"].ToString());
        var month = int.Parse(jObject["month"].ToString());
        var day = int.Parse(jObject["day"].ToString());

        existingValue = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(year, month, day));

        return existingValue;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(DateTimeOffset) == objectType;
    }
}
```

Your `Person` class should look like this:

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeOffsetConverter))]
    public DateTimeOffset Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

and the `Meeting` class should not be changed. By using the following lines to convert objects of type `Person` or `Meeting` you'll get the desired output:

```
var p = new Person
{
    Birthday = DateTimeOffset.Now
};

var m = new Meeting
{
    Date = DateTimeOffset.Now
};

var personString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
var meetingString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m);
```

For deserialization of `Person` object from `personString` you can use the following line:

```
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(personString);
```

Comment: +1.  Since the original question did mention deserialization as well as serialization, it would be helpful to show the implementation of the ReadJson method, instead of throwing a NotImplementedException.